# Android layout orientation issue

Tags: android, layout

I need to create new activity in my project, and I want to show pictures. The layout that I want to create is like that.

[image]

All heights must have "wrap_content" property.

Which layouts I must use?

Comment: You should understand that using "wrap_content" on two top grids doesn't guarantee the equality of their heights.

Comment: So you want to put 3 GridLayouts?

Comment: I dont want to use GridLayout, because it requires API Level 14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="66" >
        </GridView>

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="33" >
        </GridView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Note**: you can use any other View instead of GridView just make sure the attributes are the same.

[image: This is what you're looking for]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create an StaggeredGridView.

StaggeredGridView is a modified version of Android’s experimental StaggeredGridView. The StaggeredGridView allows the user to create a GridView with uneven rows similar to how Pinterest looks. Includes own OnItemClickListener and OnItemLongClickListener, selector, and fixed position restore.

Use [this](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo) library.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) or a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) and use the attribute **layout_weight** on the children.

Your first child (66%) can have a layout weight of 2, the second (33%) a layout of 1.

Then the first child will occupy 2/3 of the width (66%) and the second child 1/3, that is 33%.

And use the **layout_span** attribute to expand the last view on the two columns.

For example :

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Also see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean) for an explanation on layout_weight.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you insist on using wrap_content? 
You have "fixed" width of boxes (66% and 33%). You can use sp/dp units to achieve this, I am sure. With some tweaking, of course.

For more info regarding this topic go to 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
and
[What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)